# window.event.srcElement.options NOT Work on FF

Tags: javascript

`window.event.srcElement.options(window.event.srcElement.selectedIndex).value` works in Internet Explorer (and Chrome) but not in FireFox. How to make this work in FireFox as well?

Answer (score 2):

`event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].value`. Though as always with events you'd have to have passed the event object into a function, so eg.:

```
<script>
    function selectChanged(event) {
        var target= event.target || event.srcElement;
        doSomethingWith(target.options[target.selectedIndex].value);
    };
</script>

<select onchange="selectChanged(event)">...</select>
```

Setting the handler directly and using `this` may be easier:

```
<select id="x">...</select>

<script>
    document.getElementById('x').onchange= function() {
        doSomethingWith(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
    };
</script>
```

Note that looking at `options[selectedIndex]` is for compatibility with older browsers. These days you can usually just get away with saying `select.value`.

Comment: +1 This nailed it for me. Same exact problem, but with a dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

```
var addEvent = (function() {
function addEventIE(el, ev, fn) {
    return el.attachEvent('on' + ev, function(e) {
    return fn.call(el, e);
    });
}
function addEventW3C(el, ev, fn) {
    return el.addEventListener(ev, fn, false);
}
return window.addEventListener ? addEventW3C:addEventIE;
})();

var domRef = document.getElementById('foo');

addEvent( domRef, 'change', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var el = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement,
        value = el.value;
    alert( value )
});
```

in IE, `event` is a property of window, in modern DOM supporting browsers it's passed as the first argument.

Comment: or in jQuery, use e.target, which is set to srcElement in the case of IE.

Comment: Why must every single Javascript question resolve to some jQuery answer/comment?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:
Assume there is markup

```
<SELECT name="ddlQuery" id="ddlQuery" style="width:273px;"
        onchange="GetDropDownValue(event)">
...
```

on HTML.

One using js function:

```
function GetDropDownValue(e)
{
    var rtnVal = "";
    var sel = document.getElementById(getTargetID(e));
    for (var i = 0; i < sel.options.length; ++i) {
        if (sel.options[i].selected == true) {
            rtnVal = sel.options[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }
    alert(rtnVal);
    return rtnVal;
}

function getTargetID(e) {

    if (!e) { var e = window.event; }
    var objTarget = e.srcElement ? e.srcElement : e.target;
    return objTarget.id;
}
```

another using jQuery:

```
$('#ddlQuery').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no global `event` object in Firefox. Events are passed to their handlers as an argument. Also, instead of `srcElement`, you look for `target`.

If you use a javascript library like jQuery, all the browser specific quirks are handled for you.

Otherwise, I suggest you to read these articles

- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html
- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

Answer (score 0):

IE uses `srcElement` where most other browsers (including Firefox) use `target`.

Also, Firefox passes around event objects, whereas IE just populates the global event object w/the current event's data.

You'll have to handle both in your code.  How you handle the 2nd one will depend on how you're assigning the handler.

But here's one way.

```
function changeHanlder( event )
{
  var elem = event.target || event.srcElement;
  alert( elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value );
}
```

It's also worth noting that all the modern javascirpt libraries handle this abstraction for you.

Comment: So where does this "e" come from? I think you meant event.target || event.srcElement.

Comment: @Maiku - indeed, where is that `e` coming from?  Fixed (thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox uses e.htmlEvent.target.nodeName

you can use **try/catch** to handle both browsers.